# How can I suppress the 'is up to date' message from Make?

Tags: makefile

How can I tell Make to stop logging

```
make: `foo.o' is up to date
```

When foo.o is up to date?

Comment: You can use the `-s` (silent) option to suppress that message (it will suppress lots of other output as well however).  Note, make only reports whether the command-line goal you requested is up to date: it doesn't report that for every target in the makefile.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for, would you be up for submitting your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `-s` / `--silent` option to `make` to suppress output; from [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options-Summary.html):

```
‘-s’
‘--silent’
‘--quiet’
Silent operation; do not print the recipes as they are executed. See Recipe Echoing.
```

It doesn't say so explicitly but this also suppresses other types of informative output.